# Where is the Toolbar in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse-luna

I've just updated to Eclipse Luna, but the toolbar is missing. Window -> Show Toolbar/Hide Toolbar does nothing at all. In Window -> Customize Perspective, everything looks normal. This is the first time I opened Luna, and I've imported an old Kepler workspace. Any Ideas?

**EDIT:** The error only occurs, when I open eclipse from the desktop shortcut, not directly through the .exe...

From the error log (not sure if this is relevant, but it might be):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-01-07 13:31:02.028
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.OptionalMessageDialog.buttonPressed(OptionalMessageDialog.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.informUserAboutEmptyDefaultCategory(ContentAssistProcessor.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.getDefaultCategories(ContentAssistProcessor.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.getCategoryIteration(ContentAssistProcessor.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.setCategoryIteration(ContentAssistProcessor.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.access$3(ContentAssistProcessor.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor$CompletionListener.assistSessionStarted(ContentAssistProcessor.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.fireSessionBeginEvent(ContentAssistant.java:2305)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.prepareToShowCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1718)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.showPossibleCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor$AdaptedSourceViewer.doOperation(CompilationUnitEditor.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction$1.run(ContentAssistAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction.run(ContentAssistAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4722)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4610)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Have you got error messages during the import? Do you see errors in the Error log? (I guess with a new workspace it works as usual, I had no such problems.)

Comment: I got "this workspace is created with an older version of eclipse. to open it, it needs to be converted. If you convert it, it might not be compatible with older versions of eclipse anymore." Not the same wording, but the gist of it. I'll check the error log now

Comment: lot's of stuff in the log. Nothing that is obviously about my problem, but I found something that might help. I'll add it to the question, and search up more info on the messages myself too...